# MSCRM 2011: Sending a reply email via code?

Tags: email, dynamics-crm

[Sending a reply email via code]

Currently i am opening an email activity and manually sending replies to them by clicking on the reply button in the form.

I have written a plugin which triggers on creation of an email activity and sends out an notification email to the sender of that email activity.
But it goes out as a fresh email activity and not a reply.

**Email should go out as a reply and not a fresh email.**

Please help.

Regards,

Aamir Nawaz

Answer (score 0):

If the e-mail you reply to does not have anything in the "Regarding" field, then the reply would also not have.

Depending on your use case, the incoming e-mail could be connected to a case, an account or an activity (typically).

In your code you should set the Regarding accordingly. If you do not have a Regarding in the original e-mail I would suggest reviewing your business case and decide on the flow.

In our system, if an e-mail is recieved it is scanned for CAS-###### reference in subject and body. If found it is connected to the existing case, if not a new case is created using either the known contact as customer or a place holder account (awaiting a CSR to create/correct contact and case). The creation of the case triggers an acknowledgement e-mail to the contact with case reference information. This e-mail is connected to the case.

I hope this helps you. 
Br Nicolai